# Changing button color for period of time

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to change the button when the button is pressed. This color will Stay for 3 seconds, and the the normal color will come back. For example, the normal color is grey, when pressed the button will stay blue for 3s and the turn grey again.
This is what I was attempting:

```
_hasBeenPressed = false;
onTap: () {
        setState((){
          Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), (){
            _hasBeenPressed = !_hasBeenPressed;
 print("inside" + _hasBeenPressed.toString()); //prints true
          });
          _hasBeenPressed = !_hasBeenPressed;
 print(_hasBeenPressed); // prints false
        });
      },
```

When printing the "inside" prints after the second print
This is the decoration:

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: _hasBeenPressed ? Colors.grey[800] : Colors.blue , 
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60)
        ),
```

When I press it once I get the color change, but when the Timer finishes the color doesn't change back to grey, only if I reload the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the *inside* `_hasBeenPressed = !_hasBeenPressed` in a `setState`.

Comment: Isn't calling a setState inside a setState a bad thing?

Comment: It is, but here, we are not actually calling it within the outer setState. It is being called by the Timer asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RawMaterialButton to avoid too much code for changing the color

[image: FlashButton]

```
    RawMaterialButton(
          child: Text('Hello'),
          shape: CircleBorder(),
          constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 100, height: 100),
          onPressed: (){}, 
          highlightColor: Colors.greenAccent ---> mention the highLightColor
    )
```

Comment: I can't use a Material Button because the app doesn't relay on that, I use a Gesture Detector to create a CUSTOM button